# How start clockwork in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

clockwork https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

I run following commands in ubuntu production server. Not work.

```
bin/clockwork clock.rb -e production
bin/clockwork clock.rb RAILS_ENV=production
```

I run following command in local develop mac. It`s work.

```
bin/clockwork clock.rb
```

clock.rb

```
require 'clockwork'
require_relative './config/boot'
require_relative './config/environment'

module Clockwork
    every(1.day, 'solr.indexing', :at => '02:00') { SolrIndexingJob.perform_later }
end
```

Comment: reprogram it with rails task, i.e. put it as a task to lib/tasks, and put requirement to environment subtask

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: 
you can run `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`
and run all codes of clock.rb in console.

and then, you check log/production.log to find "Error"